# Half exact functor which is neither right exact nor left exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

A half exact functor is a functor F (between abelian categories) such that for every short exact sequence:
$$ 0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$$
then
$$F(A) \to F(B) \to F(C)$$
is exact. Does anyone has an example of a half exact funtor that is not right nor left exact? What about a functor between abelian categories that is not right nor left nor half exact?

Comment: Not half exact: taking second (or higher) tensor power: $A \mapsto A \otimes A$ (even for finite dimensional vector spaces).

Comment: You probably want to assume your functors are additive to avoid trivialities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common source of half-exact functors which are neither right-exact nor left-exact is derived functors, which are always half exact by the long exact sequences relating them but are rarely right-exact or left-exact.  For instance, if $n>0$ and $A$ is any object of projective dimension $>n$, then the functor $\operatorname{Ext}^n(A,-)$ is half-exact but neither right-exact nor left-exact.

Here's a particularly simple example.  Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of chain complexes of vector spaces (over your favorite field $k$), let $\mathcal{D}$ be the category of graded vector spaces, and let $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ take a chain complex to its homology.  Then $F$ is half-exact by the long exact sequence in homology associated to a short exact sequence of chain complexes.  But $F$ is neither right-exact nor left exact, precisely because the connecting homomorphisms in those long exact sequences can be nontrivial.  Explicitly, if $A$ is the chain complex $0\to 0\to k \to 0$, $B$ is the chain complex $0\to k\stackrel{1}\to k\to 0$, and $C$ is the chain complex $0\to k\to 0\to 0$, then the obvious short exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is taken by $F$ to a sequence which is exact only in the middle.

For a simple example of an additive functor which is not half-exact, consider the functor $F:Ab\to Ab$ which sends an abelian group to its subgroup of elements divisible by $2$.  To see that it is not half-exact, consider what it does to the short exact sequence $0\to 2\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to 0$.

Comment: Eric's examples are more natural, but another simple way of coming up with a half-exact functor that is not right or left exact is just to take the direct sum of a left exact functor (that is not right exact) and a right exact functor (that is not left exact).