# Example additive functor which is neither right exact nor left exact.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, abelian-categories

I have a problem a bout finding an example for this problem

Give an example of an additive functor $T : Ab\rightarrow Ab$ which is neither right exact nor left
exact.

I can not think in one example for that, i would appreciate any hint about this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507311/half-exact-functor-which-is-neither-right-exact-nor-left-exact You might want to take a look at the examples in Eric's answer

Comment: The answer is one functor that is not half-exact, I do not see how to use it  for my case.

Comment: I should have specified, sorry. I meant the very first example, $\text{Ext}^n(A,-)$ for some abelian group $A$ of projective dimension bigger than $n$.

Comment: You could probably also compose a right and left exact functor. In general the composite should be not either left or right exact I think.

Answer (score 3):

Just so that this gets answered, let's apply my suggestion from the comments. Though it's even easier if we take $T$ to be the direct sum of a left exact and a right exact functor, as follows.

Define $T$ by $T(A) = \newcommand\Ab{\mathbf{Ab}}\newcommand\Z{\Bbb{Z}} \Ab(\Z/2,A) \oplus (A\otimes \Z/2)$.

Then consider 
$$0\to \Z \newcommand\toby\xrightarrow\toby{2}  \Z \to \Z/2\to 0. $$
tensoring with $\Z/2$ gives 
$$0\to \Z/2 \toby{0} \Z/2\toby{1} \Z/2 \to 0,$$
which is no longer left exact. Taking $\Ab(\Z/2,-)$ we instead get 
$$0\to 0 \to 0 \to \Z/2 \to 0,$$
which is no longer right exact.

Taking the direct sum, we get
$$0\to \Z/2 \toby{0}\Z/2 \toby{\iota_1} (\Z/2)^2 \to 0,$$
which is not left or right exact.